# Reading Array Values in a dynamically created array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have created an array as below:

```
$this->db->order_by('mnth','desc');
$this->db->select("users.name,users.address,awards.*");
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('awards', 'users.sno = awards.mem');
$res = $this->db->get();
$resbygroup = array();
foreach($res->result_array() as $row)
{
 $resbygroup[$row['mnth'].",".$row['yr']][]=($row['name'] . ", " . $row['address']);
}
if($res->num_rows()>0)
{
 return $resbygroup;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

The purpose is to show the list of winners grouped by month and year.
In view, when I put var_dump over the returned result, I get the following output:

```
array(3) { ["9,2018"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "name1, addr1" [1]=> string(31) "name2, addr2" [2]=> string(30) "name3, addr3" [3]=> string(37) "name4, addr4" [4]=> string(46) "name5, addr5" } ["8,2018"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "name7, addr7" } ["6,2018"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "name8, addr8" } }
```

I want to fetch the results and show them Month,Year wise.
I tried the following code:

```
foreach($res as $r)
{
 for($x=0;$x<count($r);$x++)
 {
  echo"<br>";
  echo $r[$x];
  echo"<br>";
 }
}
```

It shows name, address pair perfectly, but I also want to show the mnth, yr pair. Output should be like:

> 9,2018: name1, address1 | name2, address2 | name3,address3 and so on
>
> 8,2018: name7,address 7 | and so on

Please tell how to achieve this

Comment: Just assign the key in your [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop too and echo it before the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
foreach($res as $r=>$val)
{
 echo $r; // gives mnth,yr
 for($x=0;$x<count($val);$x++)
 {
 echo $val[$x]; //gives name,address
 }
}
```